# What do the -n and -a options do in a bash if statement?

Tags: bash

What function do the `-a` and `-n` options perform in the following bash `if` statement?

```
if [ -n "$1" -a -n "$2" -a -n "$3" ]; then
    REFNAME=$(basename $3)
else
```

Are `-a` and `-n` so called *[primaries](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html)*?

Does `-a file` mean "True if file exists."?

Comment: -n string True if the length of string is non-zero.
-a file True if file exists.

Comment: `[` is a bash command itself. Do `man [`. Search for `-n`. Scroll/search till you see: "-n string     True if the length of string is nonzero"

Answer (score 50, accepted):

#### Nitpicking

The switches `-a` and `-n` are not strictly part of a `bash` `if` statement in that the `if` command does not process these switches.

#### What are primaries?

I call them "switches", but the `bash` documentation that you linked to refers to the same thing as "primaries" (probably because this is a common term used when discussing parts of a boolean expression).

#### Background and docs

In `sh` scripts `if` is a command that takes a command as its argument, executes it and tests its return code. If the return code is `0` the block of code following `then` is executed up until the closing `fi` or (if supplied) the following `else`. If the return code was not `0` and an `else` statement was supplied then the block of code following `else` is executed up until the closing `fi`.

You can see this effect by passing `if` the command `true` or the command `false`, which are simple commands that do nothing and return `0` and non-`0` respectively.

```
if true ; then echo true was true ; else echo true was false ; fi
if false ; then echo false was true ; else echo false was false ; fi
```

In the sample code you provided the command that you're passing to `if` is `[`, which is also sometimes known as `test`. It is this command which takes the switches you're asking about. In `bash` the `test` command will be a built-in command; try `type [` to learn its type. For built-in commands `help` will show usage, so also run `help [` to see documentation. Your system probably also has a `/bin/[` and a `/bin/test` and if you `man test` you can see the manuals for those. Although the behavior of the built-in `test` may not be identical to the behavior documented in the man pages, which is likely more verbose than the simple description you'll get from `help [`, it will probably describe the behavior of the built-in `[` command fairly accurately.

#### The behavior of -a and -n

Knowing that the command you're running is `test` we can consult `help test` or `man test` and read its usage. This will show that`-n` tests the following argument and evaluates to true if it is not an empty string.

In the documentation of `test` you will also see a the switch `-e`. This switch tests the following argument and evaluates to true if that argument is a file or directory that exists. More useful still is the `-f` switch which evaluates to true if the following argument exists and is a regular file (as opposed to a directory or a block device, or whatever).

The source of your confusion is probably that there can be **two** forms of `-a`: Unary and binary. When `-a` is used in a unary context, that is with *one following argument* but *no preceding arguments*, it treats its argument as a file and tests for its existence, just like the `-e` switch. However, when `-a` is used in a binary context, that is with *one argument before it and one argument after it*, it treats its arguments as other conditions and acts as a boolean AND operator.

In the interests of portability it is important to note that unary `-a` is a non-standard extension which [won't be found](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) in POSIX. It is available in `bash` and `ksh`, however, so usage is probably widespread.

#### Example

```
cd /tmp
if [ -a test-file ] ; then
    echo 1: test-file exists
else
    echo 1: test-file missing
fi

touch test-file

if [ -a test-file ] ; then
    echo 2: test-file exists
else
    echo 2: test-file missing
fi

var=somerthing
if [ -n "$var" -a -a test-file ] ; then
    echo variable var is not empty and test-file exists
fi
rm -f test-file
```

Comment: It would be nice if this answer described the behaviour of -n under the sectioned entitled "The behavior of -a and -n".

Comment: I've read your answer from top to bottom and it doesn't answer the question. We're not interested in nitpicking, it is not what the OP asked. He asked about `-a` and `-n` and I still don't know how `-n` works.

Comment: I will quote from the above: "This will show that `-n` tests the following argument and evaluates to true if it is not an empty string." -- the example also demonstrates this.

Comment: Why start with a nitpick? Why not answer the question directly up front then go into whatever details are necessary for a deeper understanding of the answer?

Comment: 'Primary' is a term from parser design. It refers to something at the lowest level of the parse tree: a constant, or identifier, or somesuch.

Answer (score 220):

`-a` Links two expressions together in an "and" or "&&" expression. This option is [deprecated](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).

`-n` Checks if the length of a string is nonzero.

You could translate the test expression into the following pseudocode:

```
if ( ($1 has nonzero length) and
     ($2 has nonzero length) and
     ($3 has nonzero length) )
```

There are no checks in that expression for whether the file exists or doesn't exist, only whether the arguments have been supplied to the script.

The arguments `-a` and `-n` can be found in the manpage for `test`

```
man test
```

The operator `[ ... ]` is often used as shorthand for `test ...` and likely has identical functionality on your system.

Comment: Never expected this question to get so much attention because it is _so specific_. I'm really curious how people keep finding this so useful?

Comment: It's useful because your answer is like the TL;DR version of the accepted answer, for people who want to quickly understand what `-a` and `-n` do without reading a wall of text

Comment: I meant I'm curious how people keep finding this _question_  about `-n` and `-a`. I mean, what are you Googling for? Searching for single character command line arguments... I probably couldn't find this question on Google if I tried.

Comment: @CoryKlein, I googled the following: bash command "if -n"

Comment: I was looking for examples of 'if' in Bash: `site:stackoverflow.com bash if`

Comment: Worth noting that the logical inverse of `-n` is `-z` so `[ -n "$string" ]` is equivalent to [ ! -z "$string" ]` (`-z` is true if the string is zero length)

Comment: @CoryKlein I searched for `bash what is dash n` and got here.

Comment: "The arguments -a and -n can be found in the manpage for test"
So useful, thank you!

Comment: @CoryKlein I googled 'bash "-n" flag' and this was the second result.